# Change in behaviour of dataclasses

Tags: python, transcrypt

I am working on release 3.7.1 of the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org/) Python to JavaScript compiler.
Part of the release procedure is a shipment test, in which Transcrypt is tested back to back with CPython.

It used to run flawlessly with the beta's of CPython 3.7, but with the release there's a problem.

The program:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclass
class Test:
    x: ClassVar = 10
    y:  int = 10

t = Test ()

t.x = 20

print (repr (t))
```

used to print (using CPython):

```
Test(x=20, y=10)
```

but with the release it prints (again just using CPython):

```
Test(y=10)
```

So it leaves out the class variable x from the representation.
Can anyone tell my whether or not this change is intentional,
and where I can find a discussion that justifies it?

With this change Transcrypt behaves differently from CPython, which I don't want.
So I wonder should I adapt Transcrypt or should I consider this a CPython regression and wait for it to be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables):

> 30.6.3. Class variables
>
> One of two places where [`dataclass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) actually inspects the type of a
>   field is to determine if a field is a class variable as defined in [PEP
>   526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526). It does this by checking if the type of the field is `typing.ClassVar`. If a field is a `ClassVar`, it is excluded from
>   consideration as a field and is ignored by the dataclass mechanisms.
>   Such `ClassVar` pseudo-fields are not returned by the module-level
>   [`fields()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) function.

So, this appears to be an intentional change.